# Collect Request of partial save implementation

Tags: javascript, html, save, partial

- how to get the collect partial save request on DOB ( date of birth[xx/xx/xxxx] ) field.
- Mention that how to get the request from the below mentioned field
  [Date of birth field]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For a better chance on getting useful answers, please provide more details on your question.

Comment: How to get the collect partial save request for DOB field using java script.